# Yii 2 custom dropdown menu with items not working

Tags: php, function, drop-down-menu, yii2

I'm creating my own dropdownlist function in [Yii 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii). I created a function and a view and in the view I have multiple items inside of my dropdown form.

```php
<?= $form->customDropDown($dpForm, 'color', [
        'items' =>
            [
                'label' => 'red',
                'value' => 'red',
                'options' => [
                    'style' => 'color: red'
                ]
            ]
            [
                'label' => 'blue',
                'value' => 'blue',
                'options' => [
                    'style' => 'color: blue'
                ]
            ]
    ]
```

And the function I made looks like this (it uses and is located in ActiveForm):

```php
    public function customDropdown($model, $attribute, $items = [], $options = [])
    {
        $value = Html::getAttributeValue($model, $attribute);

        $field = $this->field($model, $attribute, $options);

        return $this->staticOnly ? $field : $field->dropDownList($items);

    }
```

The problem is that when I open my dropdown, everything is either an option or an optgroup instead of just options with a label and a style.

How it looks like in *[Inspector](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/page_inspector/how_to/open_the_inspector/index.html)*:

```html
<optgroup label='0'>
    <option value="label">red</option>
    <option value="value">red</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="options">
    <option value="style">color: red</option>
</optgroup>
```

And so on. What I want looks like this:

```html
<option value="red" style="color: red">red</option>
```

But I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired output where each item in the dropdown is represented by a single `<option>` tag with the specified label, value, and style, you need to modify your code as follows:

In your view file, update the `customDropDown` function call to pass the items array correctly:

```
<?= $form->customDropDown($dpForm, 'color', [
        [
            'label' => 'red',
            'value' => 'red',
            'options' => [
                'style' => 'color: red'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'blue',
            'value' => 'blue',
            'options' => [
                'style' => 'color: blue'
            ]
        ],
    ]
); ?>
```

Updated method:

```
    public function customDropdown($model, $attribute, $items = [], $options = [])
{
    $value = Html::getAttributeValue($model, $attribute);

    $field = $this->field($model, $attribute);

    $options['options'] = array_column($items, 'options');
    $options['prompt'] = '';

    return $this->staticOnly ? $field : $field->dropDownList(array_column($items, 'label', 'value'), $options);
}
```

In this updated version, we pass the $options array directly to the `dropDownList` method and use `array_column` to extract the label-value pairs from the $items array.

Comment: Thanks but because $options isn' t an array anymore when you put it in the return it gives an error and when I add (array) infront of it, it does show but in one option with a giant string that goes on like this: <optgroup label="0">
<option value="label">Give You Glory</option>
<option value="value">GiveYouGLory</option>
<optgroup label="options">
<option value="style">font-family: GiveYouGLory</option>
</optgroup>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="1">
<option value="label">Architects Daughter</option>
and so on

Comment: Thanks! Only the options still do not work. I get the options right but the style="color:red" and so on is still missing.

Comment: This answer looks like it's mostly ChatGPT generated

Comment: As I've mentioned several times in comments on your answers over the last few weeks, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, I'd encourage you to delete it.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: @DavidW Have you any other options for the questioner? :) other than posting this thing?